# Clear cache Laravel automatically

Tags: caching, routes, laravel-8

There are any way to clear cache every day or every time interval automatically not manually ? 
no for clearing cache I run `php artisan opimize` in the server ( to clear all caches), but it's not parctice, also I defined a route to clear cache like this :

```
//Clear cache
Route::get('/clear-cache', function() {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('cache:clear');
});
```

but I don't know how to execute this route automatically

Answer (score 1):

You can use task scheduler from Laravel [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling)

You can create CRON Job for it then run it for given period.

1. You should create a job for your it (you may just use 2. item but it is not proper)
2. Add your job and add period in App\Console; **schedule** function like:

   ```
    $schedule->call(function () {
        Artisan::call('cache:clear'); // you can move this part to Job
    })
    ->daily();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
$schedule->command('cache:clear')->monthly();
```

to clear cache every month.